# Using register variable to store values for multi host play

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook which contains two plays, the output of first play is to be  used by the second. So I'm using register variable to store the output. The problem is my play is intended to work on multi hosts rather than single host and the output of register is overridden each time and I don't have the values for last (n-1) executions.

My playbook looks like this:

```
- name: Perform task 
  hosts:  db_server
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    - method: "{{ method }}"

  roles:
    - {role: run_custom_module, tags: ["maintenance"]}


- name: Second task based on output of first
  hosts:  db_server
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    - method: "{{ method }}"

  roles:
    - {role: run_custom_module, when: result=="some_string"}
```

The role run_custom_module looks like this:

```
- name: Executing the custom module
  run_custom_module:
      task: "Run custom py module"
      var: "{{ method }}"
  register: result
```

The inventory file looks like:

```
[db_server]
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

In case of with_items, the register variable store the output in a list called **results**, refer [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop). On similar grounds, how can I store the output of multi host play in the register variable so that it can be used in second play of the same playbook?

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: How can I access the output generated by each host in a play? It gets overridden. :(

Comment: Just like you do in the code you posted. A registered variable is like a fact, Ansible stores values for each host separately.

Comment: @techraf The issue is the final value of register variable "result" contains only the output generated by host 3.3.3.3 and not 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2. I however, need a datastructure that can store the o/p of all the 3 hosts.

Comment: Nope, it's not.

Comment: `result` is a fact specific for each host, so every host has its own `result`.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov How can I access that in the next play? Is it a 'dict' ?

Comment: Yes, registered variable is always a dict. Print it with `debug: var=result` and see what's there.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Registered variables are facts. You can access facts on other hosts with `hostvars`.

For instance, you could access `result` registered variable for host `1.1.1.1` with `hostvars['1.1.1.1'].result`.

You can list all hosts in a group with `groups`.

For instance, you could list all hosts in `db_server` group with `groups['db_server']`.

To wrap things up, you could try something like this :

```
---
- hosts: db_server
  tasks:
    - ping:
      register: result

    - debug: var=hostvars[item].result
      with_items: "{{ groups['db_server'] }}"
```